# What does "timeouts are used to physically disconnected by the device" in serial (RS232) communications?

Tags: node.js, serial-port, node-serialport

I'm implementing serial protocol that states that after sending a particular byte, the emitter must wait X seconds to receive a response and if no response is received within the specified time, communication must timeout.

In the doc, it states:
"Time-outs are used to physically disconnect the line."

But what does "physically disconnect the line" mean in pratical terms?

I see two possibilities.

- clear my reception stream and revert to initial state in communication
- or "Closing the port / reopening it" but I don't see any particular need in this operation since If i close my COM Port, the device in other end of the line wont know that the port com was closed on my side. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It means you'd be expected to unplug the connector from the device.  Doesn't make much sense, unless the device is powered from one of the handshake lines and disconnecting and reconnecting it will reset it.  You ought to link to a website that describes the device and the protocol.

Comment: @HansPassant it's concerto protocol (1042) for payment terminals. I just want to to be certain that i'm implementing timeouts as they are suppose to be implemented. I found a related question in node serialports (https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport/discussions/2316)

Answer (score 0):

So, I would like to provide some precisions from what I could conclude after having completed the implementation.

The citation is in my opinion totally inaccurate which can lead to confusion.

The communication is composed by different states when starting a communication session as master, same goes for slave.

Here are the states from master perspective:

- initial state (not receiving and not sending) - Nothing is going on... At this phase we can become master or slaves at any time

Becoming a master:

1. send byte to ask if we can init communication (wait x ms then reset if nothing is received)
2. waiting_for_ack: wait x ms then reset if nothing is received
3. if ack was received send data command and enter wait_for_data_ack for X ms. If no response, reset.

By reset I mean revert to initial state.
And if you desire retry a few seconds later to init the communication.